# How to convert this loop into raw math

Tags: math, lua

I've been at this for around an hour, I'm too shook after an incident to figure it out. The loop works as intended but with the cost of performance. Trying to figure out the equation for this to remove the loop

lua

```
local rebirthPrice= 50000000
local currentRebirth = 1

local calculatePrice = function(user,num)
    local defaultPrice = rebirthPrice*currentRebirth
    local endPrice = 0

    --
    for index = 1,num-1 do
        endPrice += rebirthPrice*(currentRebirth+index)
    end

    endPrice += defaultPrice 
    --
    return endPrice 
end

print(calculatePrice(nil, 1))

--[[
    When current rebirth == 1,
    rebirthing once should cost defaultPrice
    twice should cost 150M
    three times should be 300m etc
--]]
```

Comment: `defaultPrice` and `defPrice` the same?

Comment: no, defPrice is defined in the function as defaultPrice*currentRebirth

Comment: Well, the loop is essentially the summation of `a*(b + k)` from k = 1 to num - 1, for some constants `a` and `b`. You can apply the rules for summations to factor out `a` and then split up `b + k`. That gives you one term which is `b` times something which doesn't involve k, and another term which is the summation of k from 1 to num - 1. This last part is something you can look up. At this point you can put all the pieces together to get the whole result.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't understand what you're trying to say, this isn't my strong suite

Comment: `endPrice = (num + 2*currentRebirth-1)*num*rebirthPrice/2`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Please create an answer. Ideally an explained one.

Comment: @Yunnosch - I don't have a good answer.  It was just a hint.

Answer (score 1):

For intuition, let's apply the distributive property and rewrite your loop as:

```
for index = 1,num-1 do
    endPrice += rebirthPrice * currentRebirth
    endPrice += rebirthPrice * index
end
```

The first part contributes `rebirthPrice * currentRebirth * (n - 1)` to the `endPrice` since the loop runs `n - 1` times.

At the end you add `defaultPrice` to `endPrice` which is just `rebirthPrice * currentRebirth`.  Adding that to `rebirthPrice * currentRebirth * (n - 1)` which was contributed to the loop makes:

```
endPrice = rebirthPrice * currentRebirth * n
```

so far.

Now, what does the second equation in the loop provide to the end result?

```
endPrice += rebirthPrice * index
```

`index` is increasing: 1, 2, 3, ..., num - 1

So `endPrice` is increased by `rebirthPrice * (1 + 2 + ... + num - 1)`.

There is a formula:

```
1 + 2 + ... + x = x(x + 1)/2
```

Applying that, the second equation in the loop contributes (substituting x = num - 1):

```
endPrice += rebirthPrice * (num - 1)(num - 1 + 1)/2
```

simplifying:

```
endPrice += rebirthPrice * num * (num - 1)/2
```

So putting it all together:

```
endPrice = rebirthPrice * currentRebirth * num + rebirthPrice * num * (num - 1)/2
         = rebirthPrice(currentRebirth * num + num * (num - 1)/2)
         = rebirthPrice * num * (currentRebirth + (num - 1)/2)
         = rebirthPrice * num * (2 * currentRebirth + num - 1) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a summation rule in math that for `i=1..n` `Σ(i) = n*(n+1)/2`.

In your case you have `i=1..num-1`

```
endPrice = defaultPrice + Σ(rebirthPrice*(currentRebirth+i))
         = defaultPrice + Σ(rebirthPrice*currentRebirth) + Σ(rebirthPrice*i)
         = defaultPrice + (num-1)*(rebirthPrice*currentRebirth) + rebirthPrice*Σ(i)
         = defaultPrice + (num-1)*(rebirthPrice*currentRebirth) + rebirthPrice*(num-1)*num/2
```